# Is it possible to set an object's property value as an object within javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So here's what I'm trying todo:

Note: These objects are just an example of what I'm trying todo, they are not the actual objects I'm working with.

```
var object = {
    header: "Header",
    selectorObject: selector = new Selector(), //Property has Object value
    footer: "Footer"
}

function Selector() {
    var index = 0;
    this.rotateLeft = function() {
        index++;
        return index;
    }

    this.rotateRight = function() {
        index--;
        return index;
    }
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to give an object property value of an already defined object?

If this is possible, how do I access the object once its been assigned to the property?

I know that this is possible in another form:

```
var object = {
    header: "Header",
    selectorObject: {
     //Properties and functions
    },

    footer: "Footer"
}
```

However, my selectorObject will be used more than once, so it would be a shame to duplicate code for every object I use it in.

Comment: Are you trying to have a global selector object? Or make a selector object constructor?

Comment: you can do `selectorObject: new Selector()` or `selectorObject: selector` is that what you want?

Comment: @code I'm trying to give the object object a property that has a value of the Selector object

Comment: @hola Thanks so much! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: look at @hola comment either create a constructor that has the values and set their, or you can have a global selector object defined

Answer (score 0):

With the code above, you can just hand the selectorObject to a new instance of whatever new object you need, the instance would be the same:

```
object.selectorObject.rotateLeft()
> 1
object.selectorObject.rotateLeft()
> 2
var obj2 = { selectorObject: object.selectorObject };
obj2.selectorObject.rotateLeft()
> 3
```